# more than one mysql order by statement

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table which I need to sort the values to be arranged by gender, section and grade level using order by, does any one know how to do this?

here is my sql statement:

```
select
   * 
from
   (select
      * 
   from
     (SELECT
        distinct a.LRN,
        a.middle_initial,
        a.last_name,
        a.first_name,
        a.gender,
        a.grade_level,
        c.section_name,
        b.school_year,
        d.grade_levelnumeric 
     from
        tblstudent as a 
     inner join
        tblclass as b 
           on b.LRN = a.LRN 
     inner join
        tblsection as c 
           on c.section_id=b.section_id 
     inner join
        tblgradelevel as d 
           on b.grade_level=d.grade_level 
     where
        b.school_year = '" & Comboschoolyear.Text & "' 
     order by
        d.grade_levelnumeric DESC) as temptable 
  order by
     section_name) as temptable1 
  order by
     gender;
```

my problem is that I cannot get the output right. can any one help me? your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Use code formatting rather than typing with question.

Comment: What is being fetched wrong in your execution? Please specify bit more like what exactly do you want? Also why are you using nested query can't it work simply order by gender, section, grade_levelnumeric?

Comment: I want my output to be arrange in grade level and in grade level will be arranged in section and in section will be arranged in gender like

Grade Level                  Section                    Gender
I                                     Newton                    Male
I                                     Newton                    Female
I                                     Aristotle                   Male
I                                     Aristotle                   Female

problem is I cannot get the output right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final output would be incorrect because at outer most query you have used `order by gender`, so it will arranged by gender and it may or mayn't maintain internal sub-query's order. 
You can do this by -

```
SELECT
        distinct a.LRN,
        a.middle_initial,
        a.last_name,
        a.first_name,
        a.gender,
        a.grade_level,
        c.section_name,
        b.school_year,
        d.grade_levelnumeric 
     from
        tblstudent as a 
     inner join
        tblclass as b 
           on b.LRN = a.LRN 
     inner join
        tblsection as c 
           on c.section_id=b.section_id 
     inner join
        tblgradelevel as d 
           on b.grade_level=d.grade_level 
     where
        b.school_year = '" & Comboschoolyear.Text & "' 
     order by
        gender ASC, section_name ASC, d.grade_levelnumeric DESC
```

This will arranged the records by first gender, then section_name then grade. You can interchange grade, section and gender as your need.

Comment: thanks for the idea friend, got it with this one "select * from(SELECT distinct a.LRN, a.middle_initial, a.last_name,a.first_name, a.gender, a.grade_level,c.section_name,b.school_year,d.grade_levelnumeric from tblstudent as a inner join tblclass as b on b.LRN = a.LRN inner join tblsection as c on c.section_id=b.section_id inner join tblgradelevel as d on b.grade_level=d.grade_level where b.school_year = '" & Comboschoolyear.Text & "') as temptable order by grade_level ASC, gender, section_name DESC"